# How to remotely connect to a computer via ssh which is behind a wireless router?

Tags: ssh

At present, I'm using the wireless router TP-Link WR740N. I have tried the following two solutions in order to connect to my host computer, which is behind the wireless router:

1. Use the "virtual server" function provided by TP-Link WR740N, in which the service port 22 is mapped to the IP address of my host computer.
2. Use the "DMZ" function of the wireless router, through which my host computer will be completely open to WLAN.

However, neither the above two solutions are successful. I'm also sure that the firewall configurations of both my wireless router and host machine allow ssh communication.

Could you please help me find out the reason? Thank you!

Comment: It didn't work. **How** didn't it work? What was the error when you tried to connect? Does your router offer any kind of logs? How **exactly** did you try to connect (anonymize your IP address if you want, but consistently)?

Comment: @Gilles thanks for your reply! There is no error message from the server, the client computer just cannot connect to it until timeout. The router does not provide any log.

Comment: The problem has been solved. The ISP has blocked many ports including 22 and 8868 that I have tried. Then I tried port 443 by chance, which is the default port reserved for https, this time it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you didn't make any errors in your configurations you mentioned. If your host machine was in the DMZ and you were still getting failed connections, it's possible that your ISP blocks some traffic - in particular, traffic that is commonly associated with servers.

One workaround for this is to use a different port for your connections. You can either

- Forward a higher port (>1024) that faces the WAN to port 22 on your box.
- Configure SSH to listen on another port and forward that port to your box.

Either have the same effect. If things are still not working at that point, it's possible that your router configuration wasn't set up properly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've changed the port on which SSH server listens. However, this does not help. This is really weird.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird! Could you try running the command `netstat -a | grep "8868"` (assuming you still have sshd set up as in the comments above)?

That should report back whether `sshd` is listening on the correct port.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I cannot try this command at present because I am not at my computer. However, I'm sure that ssh is listening on port 8868 because I can log on the host computer if the client computer is in the same sub-network.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure whats the problem is but generally I go for SSH as ,

1. SSH Deamon running on Host , If running then on which port ?
2. IPTables/firewall allowed that particular port ?
3. Anything wrong with TCPWrappers ?

If you know IP of your host , simply `ssh username@hostname` or `ssh username@IPof_host` will do.

if you are getting any error let us know.
Good luck.

Comment: Hello Raja! My SSH server listens on port 22 by default and I have also tried the port 8868 according to @Nico's suggestions. Both of these ports are allowed by iptables with the following configuration:

`# Allows SSH connections
# The --dport number is the same as in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`

What is TCPWrappers? Could you please give some hints?

The command for connecting to the host is:
`ssh -p port_number username@host_ip`

There is no response after executing the above command, it is merely a timeout error.

Comment: Please let us know what the error that you are getting while trying to connect

Comment: Are you able to ping main Host IP

Comment: I can connect to the FTP server. So I think ping will also be successful.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try debugging it a bit...

- First of all, try having the ***ssh host*** and ***ssh client*** in the same network, and then, from your client do `ssh -p host_ssh_port host_user@host_ip`, to make sure everything's fine at this level. If that works, you can go to next step, if it does not, please post the output of `ssh -v -p host_ssh_port host_user@host_ip`.
- Second, configure ***Virtual Server*** on your router using `host_ssh_port` and `host_ip`, from above step, and try connecting using `ssh -p host_ssh_port host_user@router_external_ip`. If that's not working, please post the output of `ssh -v -p host_ssh_port host_user@router_external_ip`.

As a side note, considering it looks like your router can not NAT different ports (port 4022 to port 22), try having a `host_ssh_port` greater than 1024 and adapt your ***Virtual Server*** to it.